# Loading whole csv columns into an array?

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myfile = open('LoggedData_CalInertialAndMag.csv', 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(myfile)
next(reader)

a = [row[4] for row in reader]
b = [row[5] for row in reader]
```

So this is the beginning of my code that I was trying to load the whole column from the csv file to an array, and cast them to `float` later for other uses.
However, I got errors so I checked `len(a)` and `len(b)` seperately. While `len(a)` has the length 838, which `len(b)` should have the same, but it's 0.

Why? and then I changed my code using `append`, which I feel is a bit more complex. So where might I be wrong?

Comment: It will be a very sharp arrow : )

Comment: I think you mean "array" not "arrow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your first list comprehension for list `a` "consumes" the csv file as it iterates over it, so it's empty for the one for list `b`. Although not as concise as list comprehensions, I would suggest you create both lists at the same time. Also note the proper way to open a csv file for the `csv` module depends on the version of Python you're using.

```
import collections
import csv
import sys

csv_read_args = ({'mode': 'rb'} if sys.version_info[0] < 3 else
                 {'mode': 'r', 'newline': ''})

with open('LoggedData_CalInertialAndMag.csv', **csv_read_args) as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile)
    next(reader)
    a, b = [], []
    # feed generator expression into a zero-length deque to consume it
    generator = ((a.append(row[4]), b.append(row[5])) for row in reader)
    collections.deque(generator, maxlen=0)
```

An alternative to doing it this way would be to do a `myfile.seek(0)` between the two list comprehension statements to "rewind" the file back to the beginning. This would be less efficient because it requires the reader to parse the entire file twice.

**Update**

Here's another, slightly (8%-10%) faster, alternative:

```
with open('LoggedData_CalInertialAndMag.csv', **csv_read_args) as myfile:
    reader = csv.reader(myfile)
    next(reader)
    a, b = map(list, zip(*[(row[4], row[5]) for row in reader]))
```

You may not need the final `map(list, ...)` depending on whether you require `a` and `b` to be lists or not (`zip` returns a tuple in Python 2 and an iterator in Python 3).

Comment: I have used an alternative which uses append as I said in the post. I didn't use collection but your way is basically the same as what I am doing now.

Comment: I used `collections.deque` in an effort to provide something that was both efficient and concise that would allow appending data from each row to more than one list at time. I got the idea from an `itertools` module recipe called [`consume`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes). Since `deque` is provided in a built-in library, it's very fast.

Answer (score 1):

This should get your code working

```
import csv

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a, b = [], []
with open("LoggedData_CalInertialAndMag.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        a.append(float(row[4]))
        b.append(float(row[5]))
```

since you appear to be using numpy and mention reading it into arrays I assume
something like [numpy.genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) should also work

```
import numpy as np

filename = "LoggedData_CalInertialAndMag.csv"
a = np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols=[4], delimiter=',', dtype=float)
b = np.genfromtxt(filename, usecols=[5], delimiter=',', dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a call to `myfile.seek(0)` before your second call
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

`read` is reading the content of the file, when you try to load `b` all the file was already loaded, so there's nothing to look in the file :)

But a better approach would be to load both at once and then you can assign them to different arrays without reading the file again (disk I/O operations are quite expensive):

```
a = [[row[4], row[5]] for row in reader]
b = [r[0] for r in a]
c = [r[1] for r in a]
```

Comment: By seek, you meant run this function after I 've loaded the first time?

Comment: Yes, but a better approach would be to load both at once, I'll edit with this alternative.

Comment: i actually need them in two different arrays

Comment: So, just assign them to 2 different arrays, I'll edit the answer.